# Blob Storage of images and text

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-storage

I have a blob (storage account) that is housed on Azure.  I also have a sql server table that is housed on Azure.  I have a couple of questions

1. Is it possible to create a join between the blob and the table
2. Is it possible to store all of the information in the blob?

The table has address information on it and I wanted to be able to pull that information from the table and associate it or join it to the proper image by the ID in the sql table (if that is the best way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a join between the blob and the table?

No.

> Is it possible to store all of the information in the blob?

You possibly could (by storing the address information as blob metadata) but it is not recommended because then you would lose searching capability. Blob storage is simply an object store. You won't be able to query on address information.

> The table has address information on it and I wanted to be able to
>   pull that information from the table and associate it or join it to
>   the proper image by the ID in the sql table (if that is the best way)

Recommended way of doing this is storing the images in blob storage. Each blob in blob storage gets a unique URL (`https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob.png`) that you can store in your database along with other address fields (e.g. create a column called `ImageUrl` and store the URL there).

Comment: How would I get that URL from the blob to store in the table? Would I pass it as a variable in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Storage (blob, in your case) and SQL Server are completely separate, independent data stores. You cannot do joins, transactions, or really any type of query, across both at the same time.

What you store in each is totally up to you. Typically, people store searchable/indexable metadata within a database engine (such as SQL Server in your case), and non-searchable (binary etc) content in bulk storage (such as blobs).

As far as "best way"? Not sure what you're looking for, but there is no *best* way. Like I said, some people will store anything searchable in their database. On top of this, they'd store a url to specific blobs that are related to that metadata. There's no specific rule about doing it this way, of course. Whatever works for you and your app...

Note: Blobs have metadata as well, but that metadata is not indexable; it would require searching through all blobs (or all blobs in a container) to perform specific searches.